# How to convert the ranking scores into a distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Say I have a vector $V = [0.1,-0.1,0.9,0.5]$ where each element of the vector, $s_i\in{[-1,1]}$, represent the ranking score of an instance $x_i$. The higher score the instance has, the higher probability it would be selected. So I convert the vector into distribution by:
$
\begin{equation}
\frac{V+k}{\text{sum}_i{V+k}}
\end{equation}
$ where $k\in{[0,+\infty)}$ is a constant. It is like I inject a prior knowledge into this distribution, as when $k\rightarrow+\infty$, this distribution is a uniform distribution.

After I selected the sampled instance from this distribution, I will feed the instances to other models. I will adjust/tune the value of $k$ to let the model get the optimal solutions.

This sampling method performs well as I can let the model get the best performance than all the other baseline sampling methods. But it is more like an empirical method and I don't have any theory to support it. Putting this method into my paper might be criticized by the reviewers. Is there any formal statistical method to convert the ranking scores into a probability distribution?

Comment: both histogram and kernel density estimation can be employed on ranked observations when constructing distributions, but selectivity is not included since they both use all observations

Comment: You can find the ranks of observations in a sample, but the result is not the same as the distribution of a population. Example in R: `y = round(rnorm(10, 100, 15)); y` returns $137, 106, 104,  96, 101,  92, 107, 114,  92,  95.$ Then `rank(y)` returns
$10.0,  7.0,  6.0,  4.0,  5.0,  1.5,  8.0,  9.0,  1.5,  3.0.$ (Note the tie due to rounding.) It's called the 'rank transformation' of the data, sometimes useful in estimation and testing. (Examples of testing in my Answer.)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "ranking score"? And is it about ranks (transform) or about rankings (task to rank)?

Answer (score 1):

Rank transformations are sometimes made in order to use t methods (one and two-sample t tests and associated confidence intervals) when data are clearly not normal. Exact results from t methods require normal data, and ranks are not normally distributed.
However, skewed data may give inaccurate results with t methods---especially when data are severely skewed or have far outliers. However, rank-transformed data may be 'closer to normal' (without severe skewness or outliers), and thus t methods may
give useful answers.

Consider the following two samples, of sizes $n_1=n_2=20,$ sampled in R from highly right-skewed distributions:

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rexp(20, 1/40);  x2 = 10+rexp(20, 1/60)
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.175  14.307  27.844  43.941  53.750 234.701 
  [1] 51.33363      # sample SD x1
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.05   23.60   60.85   82.17   79.98  348.72 
  [1] 87.89986
```

The sample means $\bar X_1 = 43.9$ and $\bar X_2 = 82.2$ are different,
but the sample standard deviations $S_1 = 51.3, S_2 =87.9$ are large and far from
equal. The question is whether the sample means are *significantly* different,
in a statistical sense at the 5% level

```
x = c(x1, x2);  gp = rep(1:2, each=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2", pch=20, main="Original")
 boxplot(rank(x)~gp, col="skyblue2", main="Rank Transf.")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

With such skewness and outliers, most statisticians would not
not want to trust a two-sample t test to be sufficiently robust
(tolerant of non-normality) to give reliable results. However,
*ranks* of the combined sample, while pretty clearly not normal,
are roughly symmetrical and without outliers. [I use the ranks from 1 through 40, without using your scaling formula for `V`. It is sufficient to look at the ranks; this is often referred to as making a 'rank transformation; of the data.]

A Welch t test (which does not assume equal variances) on the original
data does not show a significant difference, P-value $0.19 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
t.test(x ~ gp)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x by gp
t = -1.6794, df = 30.61, p-value = 0.1033
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -84.671029   8.220889
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
   43.94103        82.16610
```

By contrast, a Welch test on the ranks (from 1 through 40) of the combined data,
does show a significant difference.

```
t.test(rank(x) ~ gp)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  rank(x) by gp
t = -2.1491, df = 37.953, p-value = 0.03807
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -14.759416  -0.440584
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
           16.7            24.3
```

A t test on ranks is somewhat similar to a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test
on the original data (which assumes samples of similar *shapes,* including nearly equal variances). A MWW test also rejects the null hypothesis, finding a significant
difference in sample 'locations' at the 5% level, P-value $0.04.$

```
wilcox.test(x ~ gp)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x by gp
W = 124, p-value = 0.04018
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

A Wilcoxon signed-rank test on ranks of data gives exactly the same P-value as above.
(The Wilcoxon test begins by taking ranks of the data.)

```
wilcox.test(rank(x) ~ gp)$p.val
[1] 0.04017508
```

Roughly speaking, the Wilcoxon SR test can be considered a test whether scores in
one of the two groups essentially stochastically dominate scores in the other group. The plot of
'empirical CDFs' (ECDF's) below shows that the ECDF of Gp 2 lies entirely to the
right of the ECDF of Gp 1, which is one definition of stochastic domination. (The ECDF of a sample of size $n$ starts at $0$ (on the left) for the smallest element of a sample and 'jumping up' by $1/n$ at each sorted observation, reaches $1$ (on the right) at the largest element of the sample.)

[image]